# In Clojure: Why unable to resolve symbol: hdcit in this context

Tags: clojure

I tried to solve the find two numbers index in a list where `nums[i]+nums[j]==target`:

```
(defn two-sum [nums target]
  "Find sum of two numbers equals to target"
  (if (<= 1 (count nums))
    nil)
  (let [hdict (hash-map)]
    (for [i (range 1 (count nums))]
      (if (get hdict (nums i))
        [(get hdict (nums i)) i]        ;return hdict[nums[i]] and i
        (assoc hdcit (- target (nums i)) i)))))
```

I got this error:

```
1. Caused by java.lang.RuntimeException
   Unable to resolve symbol: hdcit in this context
```

I'm confused: I've alread bind `hdict` as a `hash-map`, why still unable solved?

Comment: you transposed an `i` and a `c` on the last line. there are a couple other issues that are worth explaining though

Answer (score 2):

The error is a simple typo, though there are a couple other points worth considering:

- Clojure `if` expressions always return a value and if you don't specify an else clause (the second expression) then it defaults to `nil`

So the if in the code above basically says:

```
 (if contition 
   nil ;; the true case
   nil ;; the false case)
```

Always returns nil. Though since it's not the last expression in the function this value will be ignored because:

- The return value of a function (and most other expressions) is the last value in the expression.

Most likely you want to move the `)` after the `nil` to the end of the function.

- Clojure data structure are immutable, calling `assoc` on a map produces a **new map that has an additional value** while leaving the old on unchanged because someone else might be working on it.

So the `assoc` on the last line will never do anything.

- `for` is not a "for loop", rather it produces a sequence of new values, lazily, based on a very powerful expression "mini language" (DSL)

This means that it only produces a value when it's read. So this `for` loop will not run unless something prints the value. The REPL will print this and make this function work *only in development*. I call this "the lazy bug".

Immutable data is a core concept in Clojure and basically all the goodness of the language flows, at least in part, from it.

---

Clojure's **`for` expression is powerful enough to completely solve this** problem:

```
user> (let [data [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 42 12]
            target 12]
        (for [x data
              y data
              :when (= (+ x y) target)]
          [x y]))
([5 7] [6 6] [7 5])
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. It's my bad that I didn't point out that the numbers list is large - about 12 500 items; and number position/index is required, not number itself. This is why I consider using a `hash-map`. The time for `for loop` is `O(n^2)`, and using a `has-map` about `O(n)`.

Comment: In that case you need to restructure your code (likely with recursion) so that the immutable hash-map generated by assoc is added to, rather than creating a number of divergent and unmerged maps in series.

Comment: and it is worth reiterating that as @Arthur Ulfeldt points out, `for` in clojure is not a loop, it is a lazy generator of immutable values.